# Android SQLite database database /data/data/... (conn# 0) already closed

Tags: android, database, sqlite, exception

my android aplication start with query to database, but on start it return this exception:

```
03-23 20:49:10.722: E/AndroidRuntime(10499):
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tabActivity}:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{activity}:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/... (conn# 0) already closed
```

After debug I find, that error is on this line.

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, KEY_TABLE);
```

So I thing, that error is caused by locked database, but I don't know, how to repair it.
Can someone help me, how to open the database?

Comment: seems like you dont have an open database connection. post your full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for help, when I started with copy I found my mistake.

```
public DbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    dbHelper.close();
    return this;
}
```

I can't belive, that I could insert it here.